# Deleting site column from list content type and site content type

Tags: content-type, site-column

If we delete site column from list content type then will it delete from site content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, If a column 'A' associated with a content type 'X' is deleted in the list settings page, the column will be removed only in the list level and will not be removed from the site content type. So if you delete the column 'A' in list settings and go to Site content types, you will be still able to see the column 'A' in content type 'X'.